# WiX - DoAction with lower Order executed when SpawnDialog with higher Order is triggered?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I'll start by clarify a code snippet and then summarizing what it does to get to the problem I'm having. Feel free to ask any questions as I'm not a regular poster but I am aware of certain rules.

Consider the following anonymized piece of WiX UIConfiguration:

```
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="WebInstallationAddressDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>
<!--When neither Feature1 nor Feature2 will be installed we shouldn't show the WebInstallationAddressDlg -->      
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlgCustomized" Order="2"><![CDATA[&Feature1 <> 3 AND &Feature2 <> 3]]></Publish>      
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="GetIISWebSites" Order="3">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="Warning1" Order="4"><![CDATA[&Feature2 = 3 AND SKIPMESSAGE <> "1"]]></Publish>
<!--When Feature1 is set to be installed, the OS needs to be Server 2008 R2 or Server 2012 R2. So NOT (Server 2008 OR Server 2012). 
NTProductType = 1 indicates that it can't be a client type installation (not Windows 7 for example) (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa370556.aspx) -->
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="Error1" Order="5"><![CDATA[&Feature1 = 3 AND ((VersionNT <> 601 AND VersionNT <> 603) OR MsiNTProductType = 1)]]></Publish>
```

These are the options (top to bottom):

- Nothing special, transition to next dialog
- Neither of the features will be installed, skip next dialog and go to the one after that
- This condition was checking whether either of the features would be installed (to be sure the condition is true I used 1 here). This action will retrieve the Websites from IIS (what it does is actually irrelevant)
- Show a warning when installing Feature 2
- Show an error when trying to install Feature 1 on the wrong OS

What works:

- Showing both the warning and error message given their conditions

  - Only one SpawnDialog is triggered here (even if both conditions evaluate to TRUE)
- Skipping the next dialog when neither of the features is to be installed

**What doesn't work**

- Only executing the GetIISWebSites DoAction when both the SpawnDialogs evaluate to FALSE.

I have the impression DoAction doesn't care about the Order (weight) it's given and always executes when it's condition evaluates to TRUE.
What I want is this DoAction to execute when there are no warnings / errors being shown.

**Extra information**

I'm using Visual Studio (.wixproj) with a bootstrapper project to generate the Setup.exe and a third project with Custom actions.

Namespace (which is actually outdated it seems but it still works).

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I have the impression DoAction doesn't care about the Order (weight) it's given and always executes when it's condition evaluates to TRUE"

is correct. Order is the order they are run, and they will all run if the conditions are correct. If you want an action to be run only if a previous action was run (or not) then give it the same condition. It looks like you a condition of 1 on your GetIISWebSites, so yes it will always be called.

The base MSI documentation here explains that each event is called in turn.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368037(v=vs.85).aspx

Also be careful your conditions are such that you don't violate the rule about the number of dialogs that can be published. It doesn't say what will go wrong, and I don't know either.

Comment: Hello Phil, thank you for your answer.

"Always executes": When the SpawnDialogs both evaluate to TRUE, still only one is shown. Hence my impression that only the action with the highest Order would be run.
The documentation you linked mentions "The exception to note is that each control can publish a most one NewDialog or one SpawnDialog event.". This nullifies my assumption and explains this "showing only one SpawnDialog" behaviour.

Comment: Regarding the Order of DoAction I have one additional remark. Based on some tests it looks like these don't care about the Order (I tried several variations) and my final conclusion is that these actions are executed in the sequence they are written - from top to bottom.

To summarize, your answer clarifies the behavior as designed. What I have done in the meantime is to make sure the conditions are constructed in such a way, that they can only be TRUE when the SpawnDialogs won't be.